# C/C++ Puzzle: To print values from 1..15 15..1 with a single for loop

Tags: c++, c, puzzle

It was given by my colleague, to print values `1 2 3 4 .... 15 15 ..... 4 3 2 1` with only *one for loop*, *no functions*, *no goto statements* and *without the use of any conditional statements or ternary operators*.

So I employed typecasting to solve it, but it is not an exact solution since 15 is not printed twice.

```
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 1, j = 0;j < 29;j++, i += int(j/15)*-2 + 1)
        cout<<i<<endl;
}
```

**Output**: `1 2 3 4 ... 15 14 13 .... 2 1`

Any alternative solutions?

Comment: `std::cout << "1 2 3 4 .... 15 15 ..... 4 3 2 1"`;

Comment: Shubham thats not cheating, thats known as thinking out of box. That is what the interviewer was looking out for and not some fance bit manipulation or data structure technique :)

Comment: I think we need to relax the *function* constraint. Without functions, there is no C++.

Comment: I wonder, if there is a way to define such function, that it'll return 0 if its argument is lower than defined constant and 1 if the argument is higher. Integral division might help, but I guess, there is a way without using it. If one may use abs() or sgn(), it's quite easy.

Comment: @MatthieuM. We can define two available functions: main and printf (or std::cout.operator<<()) :)

Comment: Unfortunately, @Pubby solution would be rejected because there is no  for loop: 'with only one for loop'.

Comment: @Yavar: Well, it was asked by my mate, anyway. I thought of what Pubby gave but hey my second thought told me to assume certain things through your common sense. But thanks, I did'nt knew interviewer looks for these things.

Comment: @Shubham: Ha Ha, I knew your comment was bit sarcastic :). When I said that what I meant was "some" interviewers ask that, I will never ask that :) By the way good to see your profile on SO.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can loop from 1 to 30, then use the fact that (i/16) will be "0" for your ascending part and "1" for your descending part.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 31; i++)
{
    int number = (1-i/16) * i + (i/16) * (31 - i);
    printf("%d ", number);
}
```

Answer (score 25):

```
for (int i=0; i<1; i++)
{
    std::cout << "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1"
}
```

Answer (score 8):

How about this:

```
std::string first;
std::string second;

for ( int i = 1 ; i <= 15 ; i++ )
{
   std::ostringstream s;
   s << i;
   first += s.str();
   second = s.str() + second;
}

std::cout << first << second;
```

Answer (score 5):

Alternative:

```
static int bla[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) 
{        
    printf("%d\n", bla[i]);
}
```

The good one, it is faster in execution as compare to all ...

Comment: an explanation to the downvote please?

Comment: I did not downvoted, but I believe, that this is a bypass, not a solution :)

Comment: If the question didn't rule it out and it's not an intended solution then the question is poorly phrased.

Answer (score 3):

XOR bit #4 (i.e. `j & 0x10`) with bits 3:0.  You will need to find a way to "repeat" that bit into 4 positions.

Comment: Post working code so I can upvote

Comment: @Pubby: I'm leaving it as an exercise for the OP (I'm not in the habit of giving complete solutions to homework-like questions!).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I will need to bit of research for that. Not much easy with using bitwise operations. Any pages to suggest for me to read?

Comment: @Shubham: e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations.  In particular, you can take advantage of the fact that 0 ^ 15 = 15, 1 ^ 15 = 14, 2 ^ 15 = 13, ...

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i=1;i<31;++i)
{
  cout<<(((i<<27>>31|i)&(~i<<27>>31|~i))&15)<<" ";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for(int i = 1; i < 31; i++) std::cout << ((i/16)-1)*-i+(i/16)*(i^0x1F) << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have seen many *complicated* answers, yet no one exploited the symmetry *as is*.

```
std::string head = "1";
std::string tail = "1";

for (unsigned i = 2; i != 16; ++i) {
  std::string const elem = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i);

  head = head + " " + elem;
  tail = elem + " " + tail;
}

std::cout << head << " " << tail << "\n";
```

In action at [ideone](http://ideone.com/h9vVv) (minus `lexical_cast`):

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

It works simply, and for any magnitude of the upper bound (as far as your computer as enough memory).

Comment: You used a conditional statement, which is prohibited.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Your display is incorrect though (no space) :p

Comment: @Spook: corrected :) Stupid list of requirements...

Comment: You're right there. +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

```
const int N = 15;
for(int i = 1; i <= 2 * N; ++i)
    printf("%d ", i + (i > N) * (1 + 2 * (N - i)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 30; i++)
    printf("%d\n", (-((i & 16) >> 4) + 1) * i + ((i & 16) >> 4) * (14 - (i & 15)));
```

Comment: Aww crap. I missed that.

Comment: printf is a function too

Comment: cout << sth = cout.operator<<(sth), so this is function too. How shall we print anything on screen?

Comment: so is `main` :) the question has some flaws I believe.

Comment: The next time I will ask some question I will be completely precise and leaving no loopholes in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{

    for(int i = 15, j = 30, k = 15; i <= 30; i++, j--, k -= 2)
    {
        cout << (j - i) * (k % 2) << endl << (j - i - 1) * (k % 2) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This what I came up with. It goes the other way, ie: 15 -> 0 -> 15. Just more food for thought. Uses mod and k to work out if negative number. I - J meet in the middle. Its by no means perfect and there are some other better answers.

Comment: Subtract the result from 15, it'll return valid sequence :)

Comment: me being a numpty... Overall quite an interesting puzzle